# Email address through which I can update my Facebook status

Tags: facebook

There used to be an option to upload photos or post a status on Facebook by sending a mail to a specific address.

What's the process of finding this email address associated with my account?

(I'm not talking about the `@facebook.com` address associated with my account.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Click [image: the settings gear] at the top right of any Facebook page
2. Click **Settings**
3. Click the **Mobile** tab on the left side of the screen. 
   Your post-by-email address is listed towards the bottom of your mobile information.

([source](https://www.facebook.com/help/210153612350847#What-is-my-post-by-email-address?))

Answer (score 3):

**December 2013 update**

This is the link you need

https://m.facebook.com/photos/upload/?upload_source=advanced_composer&max_allowed=3

You also need to pass a user agent in your browser for a device that Facebook *thinks* doesn't support photo uploads

I use [Chrome UA Spoofer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg)

[image: Before spoof]

[image: After Spoof]

---

**Old suggestion**

Seems Facebook moved it (or is phasing it out?)

1. Go to m.facebook.com in Internet Explorer or Firefox (other browsers may redirect to a different version)
2. Select Photo
3. Under Upload via Email you should see it

Comment: This no longer appears to work.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, there's an easier way to get that email. Simply go to video upload http://www.facebook.com/video/?upload and click the Mobile Video tab.

Comment: Yup, that's definitely easier.

Comment: I get an error with that URL.

Comment: @AlE. You were getting an error almost 2 years after my original reply. Facebook changes interface too often.