# Mobile upload email address

Tags: facebook, email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Email address through which I can update my Facebook status](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/22258/email-address-through-which-i-can-update-my-facebook-status)

Where can I find my Facebook mobile upload email address?

(Once it was displayed at http://www.facebook.com/mobile but now it looks like it's moved somewhere else.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been removed from that page, but can still be found by going to video upload https://www.facebook.com/video/?upload, and clicking the Mobile Video tab.

I found this answer here: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120105075116AASJRnH